# Static Initialization is not working with c# and xaml

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here is the problem.  I made a class of enums to track difficulty level.  When I pass the level in my main It does not get passed into my OtherPage.  here is my code public sealed class GlobalVars
    {
        public enum Difficulty
        {
            Easy,
            Intermediate,
            Hard
        }
        private static readonly GlobalVars instance = new GlobalVars();
        private GlobalVars() { }

```
    public static GlobalVars Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I am doing in my main page
private void Easy_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalVars.Difficulty _difficulty = GlobalVars.Difficulty.Easy;
            //_difficulty = GlobalVars.Difficulty.Easy;
        }

Next I go to my divisionPage and do the following

initialize an instance of the class

private GlobalVars.Difficulty _difficulty;

then

if ( _difficulty == GlobalVars.Difficulty.Easy)
            {
                do something easy
           }

if ( _difficulty == GlobalVars.Difficulty.Hard)
            {
                do something hard
           }

My enum value is always easy not able to pass the other levels to this page.

Comment: @khlr here is the question with some modifications from my previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you *not* are using Enum incorrectly. Difficulty is an enum(type).
Second, you are *not* using the GlobalVars instance at all, you are always working with a local variable. Instance property has to be used to use the instance and then set the values at the level of instance.

```
GlobalVars.Difficulty _difficulty = GlobalVars.Difficulty.Easy;
```

Above statement assigns value to only the variable _difficulty but not to the static instance. If you need to carry the state or set the difficulty value, use some instance\member level variable like,

```
public Difficulty DifficultySet { get; set; }
```

Set the instance's DifficultySet from MainPage, access this value from any other page. Since you have singleton (one instance only), value set from Main page would be available with the instance.

Complete code would look like below. [Please write your own code to understand, how static, enums and instantiation works.]

```
public sealed class GlobalVars
{
    static readonly GlobalVars instance = new GlobalVars();

    public Difficulty DifficultySet { get; set; }

    private GlobalVars()
    {

    }

    public static GlobalVars Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public enum Difficulty { Easy, Intermediate, Hard };
}

//main page
GlobalVars pageInstance = GlobalVars.Instance;
pageInstance.DifficultySet = GlobalVars.Difficulty.Easy;

//other page
if(GlobalVars.Instance.DifficultySet == GlobalVars.Difficulty.Easy)
{
    //write your logic
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you for the correction.  I will follow your hints and hopefully I will get it.